# Why did the author use hiragana instead of kanji in the following examples? (長い,幼い)

Tags: kanji

Could someone please explain why someone would use hiragana instead of the regular kanji?

For instance, we have a character for nagai - 長い, but examples using ながい can also be found in dictionaries and on the internet. Is the hiragana used for emphasis, or is it just the author's taste?

Example (Tanaka Corpus):

> このながい不況の結果、社会不安が起こるかもしれない。
>
> Social unrest may come about as a result of this long recession.

Another example found: おさない instead of 幼い

> 子供はおさないときに母をしゃぶり、大きくなって父親をしゃぶる。

Comment: Note on the [Tanaka Corpus](http://www.edrdg.org/wiki/index.php/Tanaka_Corpus). These are probably more likely to be errors in the original input than a deliberate choice.

Comment: Basically every "Yamato kotoba" can be written in hiragana. We can answer questions like "why do you think the author used hiragana?" But no one but the author knows the actual reason.

Comment: @Gradius you should make that the answer.

Comment: @Paolina Dictionaries have items written in hiragana by default, which may be accompanied with writings usng kanji.

Comment: 「幼い子供はおさないときに母をしゃぶり、大きくなって父親をしゃぶる。」？？What a weird sentence...What does it mean...?

Comment: @Louis I don't think the question really works. In Japanese, actually, every "Yamato kotoba" can be written in hiragana. These kinds of phenomena are everywhere. It's up to you. おおきい can be written 大きい or おおきい as you like. Newspapers and legal documents have some rules, but others don't. If we know the contexts, we may do a kind of literary criticism.

Comment: @Gradius I agree. It's not off-topic but if it's not really answerable it would be nice to have an answer like yours. That way questions like [these](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6011/why-is-%e3%81%ab%e3%81%bb%e3%82%93%e3%81%94-sometimes-used-instead-of-%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e) can be directed (closed) here.

Comment: I just searched "ながい不況" with Google, and got a lot of copies of the same sentence as the very question says. So, we could say, this case is special and we should forget it.

Comment: @Chocolate All web pages that have this sentence that I could find were somehow related to learning Japanese and were written in English, and I found http://www.meigennavi.net/word/011/011273.htm, according to which it is a (bad) translation from a British proverb. The latter part should be translated as すねをかじる.

Comment: @sawasan, Ah I see! (The other translation on that page looks much better:子供は幼い時は母の乳を吸い、大きくなると父のすねをかじる。)

Answer (score 1):

For the first example `ながい`, I can think of a two reasons why: 1) The person who entered the text didn't really think about it or didn't care, or 2) There are two versions `永い` and `長い`, and the author didn't know which one to use (this probably isn't the case, but you never know). However, there could be other reasons, and as mentioned in the comments "no one but the author knows the actual reason".

For `おさない`, did you know there are two readings for `幼い`? There is `いとけない` and `おさない`, I don't know if that played a role in the author using hiragana, but it is something to think about (`いとけない` is generally not used very much any more, but you will still see it on occasion).

Also, it is good to know that in some situations, 漢字 are prohibited. For example, [常用外漢字]{じょうようがいかんじ} will generally not be used in newspapers because they are not part of the official set of characters to be taught. Also, words like `障害` are usually written as `障がい` recently because `害` has a negative meaning. Also, `子供` is written as `子ども` and there is some controversy over this, but I will leave the reason behind that a mystery.

Comment: Usually 永い is used only special contexts, and actually 長い is used in almost all cases. So, I don't agree that the author didn't know which one he/she should use. Moreover, いとけない is completely a obsolete word and never used in modern Japanese. Neither 長い nor 幼い has any controversial problem.

Comment: @Gradius: I mainly agree with your comments (I'll edit for clarity). However, I have known and met people firsthand that didn't know the difference between `永い/長い`, although I would agree that this isn't common.

Comment: You are partly correct about the reason 障害 is written as 障がい, but actually, 障害 is not correct in the first place. The real character for がい, 碍, is 常用外漢字, and if we follow the rule, it should be written in hiragana, so 障がい is the correct way. However, especially elder/conservative people do not prefer mixing kanji and hiragana within a word, so a sort of ateji was invented to assign 害 for がい, which became wide spread, but is not correct.

Comment: @sawa It is widely believed that 障害 wasn't used before World War II and was 障碍. However, some people reported that [障害 appeared quite a many times in documents and even laws written in the Meiji era](http://blog.motoyuki.net/2009/03/post_9be8.html). There is a [detailed research](http://research.n-fukushi.ac.jp/ps/research/usr/db/pdfs/00053-00007.pdf) about this. Considering the meanings of both the kanji and their usages in Chinese, 障碍 is more proper and should be correct, but really both 障碍 and 障害 were used even before the war.